# how to select only classes with certain title

Tags: javascript, nodelist

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("art");

for(a=0;a<buttons.lenght;a++){
  if(buttons[a].getAttribute('title') == 'jamjam'){
    buttons.splice.call(a,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in most modern browsers:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".art[title=jamjam]");
```